# Can't update ListView using Adapter

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I have such problem. I have one ListView and first of all I fill it from SQLIte database using adapter. Then I implement the search, and want to put the new search data into this ListView (method doMySearch), but I get the same result - the data is not updated. What can be done to fix it? Here is the code:

```
package com.example.citycode;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  ListView lvData,lvData1;
  DBHelper db;
  SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
  Cursor cursor;
  Cursor cursor1;

  final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
  final String LOG_TAG1 = "myLogs1";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // открываем подключение к БД
    db = new DBHelper(this);
    db.open();

    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
      doMySearch(query);
    }

    // получаем курсор
    cursor = db.getAllData();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    // Формируем столбцы сопоставления
    String[] from = new String[] { DBHelper.COLUMN_r_name, DBHelper.COLUMN_region, DBHelper.COLUMN_code};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.city_name, R.id.region_name, R.id.city_code };

    // создааем адаптер и настраиваем список
    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, from, to);
    lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listdata);
    lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);
  }

  public void doMySearch(String query) {
        lvData1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listdata);
        //Ищем совпадения
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Before get the C");
        cursor1 = db.fetchRecordsByQuery(query);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "After get the C");
        String t = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, t);
        startManagingCursor(cursor1);
        String[] from = new String[] { DBHelper.COLUMN_r_name, DBHelper.COLUMN_region, DBHelper.COLUMN_code};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.city_name, R.id.region_name, R.id.city_code };
        SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter1;

        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.item, cursor1, from, to);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Setting the adapter");
        //Обновляем адаптер
        logCursor(cursor1);
        lvData1.setAdapter(scAdapter);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Adapter was set");
      }

//вывод в лог данных из курсора
 void logCursor(Cursor c) {
   if (c != null) {
     if (c.moveToFirst()) {
       String str;
       do {
         str = "";
         for (String cn : c.getColumnNames()) {
           str = str.concat(cn + " = " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(cn)) + "; ");
         }
         Log.d(LOG_TAG1, str);
       } while (c.moveToNext());
     }
   } else
     Log.d(LOG_TAG1, "Cursor is null");
 }



     @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
               (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }


  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // закрываем подключение при выходе
    db.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: In your `onCreate` you first search with `doMySearch(query)` and then you go on with `db.getAllData();` which would overwrite your search results. For starters, try to insert a `return` after `doMySearch(query)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, you would overwrite your search result with the call to `db.getAllData()`.

Since `doMySearch` does almost the same as your `onCreate`, try removing your `doMySearch` and add the following code (replacing `onCreate`, adding `onNewIntent` and `loadData`, which performs the search or loads all data otherwise).

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get the ListView once.
    lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listdata);

    // открываем подключение к БД
    db = new DBHelper(this);
    db.open();

    loadData(getIntent());

}

// Also handle calls to onNewIntent.
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    loadData(intent);
}

// Perform a search or load all data.
private void loadData(Intent intent){
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        cursor = db.fetchRecordsByQuery(query);
    } else {
        cursor = db.getAllData();
    }

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    // Формируем столбцы сопоставления
    String[] from = new String[] { DBHelper.COLUMN_r_name, DBHelper.COLUMN_region, DBHelper.COLUMN_code};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.city_name, R.id.region_name, R.id.city_code };

    // создааем адаптер и настраиваем список
    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, from, to);
    lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works now! But why I could't change the ListView data using doMySearch method? Why data was't updated? Is your realization the best? Or it is more good to make another activity for the search? What do you think? Thanks once more!

Comment: You could use the `doMySearch` method as well, but after calling it in `onCreate` you would have to make sure to **not** fill the `ListView` with **all** results from the database (in your example, about three lines below `doMySearch` you start getting all entries from the database and setting them to the `ListView`. The way it works now there is also less redundant code, which is always a good thing. :)

Comment: Could you please show the variant with doMySearch method if possible? The onluy way to use it is not to choose all the data? But why? Your variant is certainly much better. But I'd like to understand whats wrong with my)

Comment: If you still want to use `doMySearch`, just add `return;` after calling it in your `onCreate`, before the end of the `if`-statement. As I said: in `onCreate` you search in your database and fill the list, but right afterwards you fetch everything from your database and overwrite the content of your list, so the search results will not show up.

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it as accepted, so others with a similar problem know what to fix. Thanks! :)

Comment: Or there is the third variant - to put SEARCH realization with doMySearch method at the end of onCreate, in order not to overwrite it by another data) Thanks! The answer is perfect! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `scAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` ? This is the common call whenever you want your view to reflect updates in the data.

Comment: Where should i write it? Could you please write all the code? The matter is that I tried it, but may be in wrong place..

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove de the `lvData1` and use the `lvData` in the `doMySearch`, and remove:

`lvData1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listdata);`

you have aready `findViewById` in the `onCreated`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with like this,

```
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    scAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            });
```

try this one, I have comment some lines "// Comment Tharaka" and added some lines "//DO Tharaka"

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  ListView lvData,lvData1;
  DBHelper db;
  SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
  Cursor cursor;
  Cursor cursor1;

  final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
  final String LOG_TAG1 = "myLogs1";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // открываем подключение к БД
    db = new DBHelper(this);
    db.open();

    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
      doMySearch(query);
    }

    // получаем курсор
    cursor = db.getAllData();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    // Формируем столбцы сопоставления
    // Comment Tharaka String[] from = new String[] { DBHelper.COLUMN_r_name, DBHelper.COLUMN_region, DBHelper.COLUMN_code};
    // Comment Tharaka int[] to = new int[] { R.id.city_name, R.id.region_name, R.id.city_code };

    // создааем адаптер и настраиваем список
    // Comment Tharaka scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, from, to);
    // Comment Tharaka lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listdata);
    // Comment Tharaka lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);
  }

  public void doMySearch(String query) {
        lvData1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listdata);
        //Ищем совпадения
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Before get the C");
        cursor1 = db.fetchRecordsByQuery(query);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "After get the C");
        String t = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, t);
        startManagingCursor(cursor1);
        String[] from = new String[] { DBHelper.COLUMN_r_name, DBHelper.COLUMN_region, DBHelper.COLUMN_code};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.city_name, R.id.region_name, R.id.city_code };
        SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter1;

        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.item, cursor1, from, to);

        //DO Tharaka
        lvData.setAdapter(scAdarpter);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Setting the adapter");
        //Обновляем адаптер
        logCursor(cursor1);
        lvData1.setAdapter(scAdapter);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Adapter was set");
      }

//вывод в лог данных из курсора
 void logCursor(Cursor c) {
   if (c != null) {
     if (c.moveToFirst()) {
       String str;
       do {
         str = "";
         for (String cn : c.getColumnNames()) {
           str = str.concat(cn + " = " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(cn)) + "; ");
         }
         Log.d(LOG_TAG1, str);
       } while (c.moveToNext());
     }
   } else
     Log.d(LOG_TAG1, "Cursor is null");
 }



     @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
               (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }


  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // закрываем подключение при выходе
    db.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Or I out it in the wrong place. Please show the entire code.